# JComboBox выравнивание текста

Tags: java, swing

есть кнопка-выпадающий список,в ней есть строки,что прописать чтобы текст был по центру,а не слева?
нашел вот такое,но не знаю как применить

```
(SwingConstants.CENTER)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выравнивание текста в элементах `JComboBox` можно изменить следующим образом:

```
((JLabel)comboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Аналогичный вопрос: [Is there any way to right align the text in a JCombobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641404/is-there-any-way-to-right-align-the-text-in-a-jcombobox).